# Removing jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, html

I am utilizing the jQuery UI, the accordion specifically. I wanted to add a "remove" button to each accordion that would hide it.

My current code just sets the visibility to hidden on the div. But, I need to completely remove the accordion.

Here is how I have my html laid out.

```
<div class="my-accordion">
    <h3>Accordion 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>derp</p>
        <div class="remove">REMOVE</div>  
    </div>
    <h3>Accordion 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>derp</p>
        <div class="remove">REMOVE</div>  
    </div>
    <h3>Accordion 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>derp</p>
        <div class="remove">REMOVE</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And, here is my jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".my-accordion" ).accordion();
});

// This is a giant failure.
$('.remove').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.remove').click(function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).parent('div');
    parent   // parent div of REMOVE
      .prev('h3') // catch previous h3
      .andSelf()  // parent div
      .remove();  // remove both parent div and h3
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BfKUg/2/)**

To remove the parent `div` use **[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove)**.

**OR in a row**

```
$('.remove').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').prev('h3').andSelf().remove();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BfKUg/3/)**

#### Note

It would be better if you can wrap each accordion within a `div` wrapper like below:

***HTML***

```
<div class="my-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
       <h3>Accordion 1</h3>
       <div>
        <p>derp</p>
        <div class="remove">REMOVE</div>  
       </div>
     </div>
    .....
</div>
```

and change the jQuery code like:

```
$('.remove').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parents('div.accordion-wrapper').remove();
});
```

Comment: Sure that will work to remove the div, but the heading (h3) needs to go as well. Otherwise, you have an empty accordion.

thanks for the reply.

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().remove();

Comment: ^ interesting. This made the whole accordion disappear.

Comment: Rather than multiple .parent() calls, use .parents() (note the "s") and pass the parent type. Ex: .parents(".my-accordion")

Otherwise one day, you might decide you need a div wrapping the h3s and divs, and you'll have to go back and change it to .parent().parent().parent()