# Accordion Remove Div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this accordion

```
<div id="accordion" class="accord">
    <h2>
        <a href="#">Item1</a></h2>

    <div>
        Content1
    </div>
    <h2 >
        <a href="#">Item2</a></h2>
    <div>
       Content#2
    </div>
</div>

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        animated: 'bounceslide',
        icons: { "header": "ui-icon-plus", "headerSelected": "ui-icon-minus" }
    });
```

i would like to add a link on each Item that will remove that Acoordion Div, how do i do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869622/removing-jquery-ui-accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you don't have any link to remove the DIV section.

Assuming that you have it, here is my sample.

```
$('.remove').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').prev('h2').andSelf().remove();
});
```

Comment: its not working. when deguggin in firebug i see $(this).parent('div') is  giving Object[] , but if i do parents i see list of all divs above it

Comment: also my link to remove is inside a div-table -tr-td

Comment: It depends on how you have the tags defined. Just use the correct order.. May be like $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {        $("#accordion").children("div").each(function(index, element) {
$(element).append('<div class="delete">x</div>');
$(element).children('.delete').bind('click', function() {
$(element).hide();
});
});
}(jQuery));
```